# How Do I Return getAsObject Value

Tags: jsf-2

Please how do I return gender from this method in the converter.

I have a gender entity:

```
@Entity
public class Gender implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String gender;
```

And a managedBean that uses selectItem to retreive all gender like

```
public List<SelectItem> getGenderNoList() {
    List<Gender> genderList;
    Gender gender;
    List<SelectItem> selectedGender = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    genderList = appSessionBean.getAllGender();
    for(Gender g : genderList) {
        SelectItem s = new SelectItem(g.getGender());
        selectedGender.add(s);
    }
    return selectedGender;
}
```

and a converter

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {


}
```

Comment: take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: yeah i did read dat earlier but i just nid d exact line of code. tnx

Comment: `value` should hold the gender , try System.out.println(value); inside the `public Object getAsObject`

Comment: yes tn i got the value in the printout but ls how do i return it as an object

Answer (score 0):

One Approach could be to place both Gender object : id and gender in the value of SelectItem

```
 SelectItem s = new SelectItem(g.getGender()+"UniqeSeperator"+g.getId(),g.getGender());
```

then in the `getAsObject(` do something like this

```
...
String[] tmpArr = value.split("UniqeSeperator");
return new Gender(Long.valueOf(tmpArr[0]),tmpArr[1]);
```

something like this...

Comment: Dan thanks for your help but is there not another way? plsssss

Comment: If you have some map that maps from gender to its gender value , you can use it inside the `getAsObject(` , something like this `return new Gender(someMap.get(value),value);`